# decrypt by bash same as by ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, encryption

I have decryption code by Ruby, and it works. But one of the environment I should handle isn't installed Ruby(and also cannot install for some reason), so I should rewrite another language. I chose bash because almost all environment has it, but bash script returned `digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:603`.

My Ruby code is here(decrypt correctly, want to work like it):

```rb
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

class Decryptor
  class << self

    def decryptor
      key = 'somekey' # utf-8
      iv = 'someiv' # utf-8
      OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC).yield_self { |d| d.decrypt }.tap { |dc| dc.key = key }.tap { |dcr| dcr.iv = iv }
    end

    def decrypt
      msg = "some_encrypted_message" ## actually base64 encoded
      b64_pass = Base64.decode64(msg)
      dc = decryptor
      cr.password = dc.update(b64_pass) + dc.final
    end
  end
end

Decryptor.decrypt
```

My Bash script is below:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

key = "somekey"
key=$(hexdump -e '"%X"' <<< "$key")
iv = "someiv"
iv=$(hexdump -e '"%X"' <<< "$iv")

msg = "some_encrypted_message" ## actually base64 encoded

echo $msg | openssl aes-128-cbc -d -base64 -K $key -iv $iv
```

Input key and iv in Ruby code is UTF-8 but in bash script is hex, so maybe this is the reason I cannot decrypt by bash (because when I convert them into hex as above, somehow it returned 33 bit), but I have no idea what should I do... Can anyone help me?

thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to pass the key and iv parsed hex by Ruby to bash script, and it can decrypt message correctly. So obviously how to parse them to hex is the reason I cannot decrypt. The code I used for parsing them by Ruby is below:

```rb
 'somekey'.unpack('H*').pop.scan(/[0-9a-f]{2}/).join('')
```

what the difference between above and `$(hexdump -e '"%X"' <<< "somekey")`?

Comment: you say it does not work as expected. Can you explain what happens? And why do you convert it first to hex when you think this may be a reason for failure?

Comment: Add information about them. To put it briefly, it returned error message which is `digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:603`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after visiting the manpage of hexdump, I found out this format string, which renders almost the same value as the ruby version:

```
$(hexdump -e '8/1 "%02x"' <<< 'somekey') | sed 's/..$//'
```

The sed command cuts off the last two characters (0a) of the output of hexdump.

edit:
Obviously, the <<< construct adds a newline to the string *somekey*, which is converted to hex by hexdump. Sed was used here to remove the 0a sequence. The sed call can be avoided by suppressing the newline:

```
$(echo -n 'somekey' | hexdump -e '8/1 "%02x"' )
```

...giving a bit cheaper solution.